# Using Python to extract surrounding characters of strings that appear multiple times in text

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this text:

> "At vero eos et accusamus et iusto **valor maximo** odio dignissimos
>   ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti
>   quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non
>   provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia
>   animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis
>   est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est
>   eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat
>   facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor
>   repellendus. Temporibus **valor maximo** autem quibusdam et aut
>   officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et
>   voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum
>   rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus
>   maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores
>   repellat."

Note that the string

> "valor maximo"

appears two times.
I want to get the previous and next `50` characters from each of them.

The result should contain these strings:

```
"At vero eos et accusamus et iusto"
" odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesenti"
"ssumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus "
"autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum "
```

Could be a list, dictionary, plane texts, whatever. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What is the minimum length of the repeated string? Is it at least two words? (For example the string `"et"` appears multiple times in the text, but not in the desired result)

Comment: @Recursing 4 characters

Comment: Use some regex like `"(.{0,50}(valor maximo).{0,50})"`.

Comment: @Pedro will it work for multiple occurencies? If yes, could you post an answer?

Comment: I will figure it out in a minute

Comment: Are you looking for specifically strings surrounding `valor maximo`, or all strings that repeat in the text?

Comment: strings surrounding valor maximo, in every occurence of valor maximo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess this will do:

```
import re
keyword='valor maximo'
text = """At vero eos et accusamus et iusto valor maximo odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus valor maximo autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat."""
matches = re.findall('(.{0,50}(%s).{0,50})' % keyword, text, re.DOTALL)
print(sum([match.split(keyword) for match, keyword in matches], []))
```

The general function would be

```
def get_matches(text, keyword, size):
    matches = re.findall('(.{0,%d}(%s).{0,%d})' % (size, keyword, size), text, re.DOTALL)
    return sum([match.split(keyword) for match, keyword in matches], [])
```

Comment: My output was `['At vero eos et accusamus et iusto ', ' odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesenti', 'ssumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus ', ' autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum']`

Comment: Apparently you should change "string" by "keyword", right?

Answer (score 2):

For a non regex solution, use

```
def find_searchterm(word_list, searchterm, n_hood):
    results = []
    for i, _ in enumerate(word_list):
        if word_list[i:i + len(searchterm)] == searchterm:
            results.append(word_list[max(0, i - n_hood):min(i + n_hood + len(searchterm), len(word_list))])
    return results
```

usage:

```
word_list = "At vero eos et accusamus et iusto valor maximo odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus valor maximo autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.".split(" ")


searchterm = "valor maximo".split(" ")
n_hood = 50

res = find_searchterm(word_list, searchterm, n_hood)


print(res)
```